# How can I dynamically load an image from props in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code where all the data is loaded dynamically, however the image is not loaded:

```
function ProductScreen(props) {
  const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id == props.match.params.id);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="details">
        <div className="details-image">
          <img src={product.image} alt="product" />       /* Is something is wrong here is this line */
        </div>
        <div className="details-info">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h4>{product.name}</h4>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the code where data is coming as a props

```
export default {
  products: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: "Slim Shirt",
      category: "Shirts",
      image: "images/d1.jpg",
      price: 60,
      brand: "Nike",
      rating: 3.5,
      numReviews: 21,
    }
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `/` in your `image` property assuming that you put the `image` folder in the `public` folder.

Comment: May I know where is the image file located?

Comment: export default {
  products: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: "Slim Shirt",
      category: "Shirts",
      image: "images/d1.jpg",
      price: 60,
      brand: "Nike",
      rating: 3.5,
      numReviews: 21,
    }
  ],
};

Comment: Only the image is not getting loaded, the rest of all the data is getting loaded.

Comment: I see. But may I know what specific folder do you store the actual images/d1.jpg? You may want to properly locate the relative path of the file. For example, when the ```ProductScreen.js``` and ```images``` share the same directory then you might want to use ```require('./images/d1.jpg')```.

Comment: The images are located on the public folder -> images -> d1.jpg

Comment: Try adding ```/``` in the beginning of the src string: ```/images/d1.jpg```

Comment: You can remove the ```require``` and use ```src={product.image}```